# How to stop docker rootless from using port 8080

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to use port 8080 on my local machine for a container service. Here is the relevant part of my docker-compose

```
services:
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@admin.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
      - "./data_pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin:rw"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

However, port 8080 was already in use by other process when I ran `docker-compose up`

```
Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:8080 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8080: bind: address already in use
```

I checked to see what process is listening on port 8080

```
netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':8080'
>> tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      155621/rootlesskit
```

I am using docker rootless so I guess it is using port 8080 by default. I tried killing the process but every time I ran docker-compose it is up again. Is there anyway to stop it from using this port by default?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I have another container using port 8080. After removing it I can  now use port 8080 again. My suggestion for anyone encountering the same issue is to check carefully everything with `docker images -a` and `docker container ls`. One more important thing to check is also the context in which you run your docker command with `docker context ls`.